# Ubuntu 20.04 KSM not working

Tags: 20.04, kvm-virtualization

I want to use KSM in Ubuntu 20.04 to achieve memory sharing between to qemu VMs. And I installed `ksmtuned` as follows:

```
$ sudo apt install ksmtuned
```

But I found KSM not working, and `systemctl` show as follows:

```
$ systemctl status ksm.service
● ksm.service - Kernel Samepage Merging
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ksm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2021-07-12 22:44:16 CST; 2min 39s ago
    Process: 661 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ksmctl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 661 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

7月 12 22:44:16 qhx-u20 systemd[1]: Starting Kernel Samepage Merging...
7月 12 22:44:16 qhx-u20 systemd[1]: Finished Kernel Samepage Merging.
```

```
$ systemctl status ksmtuned.service
● ksmtuned.service - Kernel Samepage Merging (KSM) Tuning Daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ksmtuned.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-07-12 22:44:16 CST; 4min 54s ago
    Process: 701 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ksmtuned (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 711 (ksmtuned)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 14194)
     Memory: 2.9M
     CGroup: /system.slice/ksmtuned.service
             ├─ 711 /bin/bash /usr/sbin/ksmtuned
             └─2394 sleep 60

7月 12 22:44:16 qhx-u20 systemd[1]: Starting Kernel Samepage Merging (KSM) Tuning Daemon...
7月 12 22:44:16 qhx-u20 systemd[1]: Started Kernel Samepage Merging (KSM) Tuning Daemon.
```

And values in `/sys/kernel/mm/ksm` are:

```
$ grep . /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/*
/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/full_scans:0
/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/max_page_sharing:256
/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/merge_across_nodes:1
/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/pages_shared:0
/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/pages_sharing:0
/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/pages_to_scan:100
/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/pages_unshared:0
/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/pages_volatile:0
/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run:0
/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/sleep_millisecs:200
/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/stable_node_chains:0
/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/stable_node_chains_prune_millisecs:2000
/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/stable_node_dups:0
/sys/kernel/mm/ksm/use_zero_pages:0
```

I've tried to use both `ksmctl start` and `echo 1 > /sys/kernel/mm/ksm/run` to start KSM but failed.

**Can anyone tell me why or how to use KSM correctly in Ubuntu 20.04?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer.

According to [Redhat doc for KSM](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/virtualization_tuning_and_optimization_guide/chap-ksm), KSM is managed by `ksmtuned` service, whose configuration file is `/etc/ksmtuned.conf`. You need to change the values in this file to activate the KSM, especifically `KSM_THRES_COEF` and `KSM_THRES_CONST`.